# Magento 2 get last query

Tags: magento2

I want to get the last query executed in a controller.

If there's a different ways in different parts i appreciate full information.

Comment: Are you trying to get the most recent MySQL query executed? Also, could you provide more details on what you are trying to do in your controller. This will help others trying to answer your question.

Comment: i want to do http://stackoverflow.com/a/31959307/6949022 but in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959307), you can use the Zend_Db_Profiler::getQueryProfiles function.

Comment: I don't know how can i put it in the code. If i want to get the query for:
$model->setData($data);
where i put the "getQueryProfiles"?